# Page Numbering Wrong In LaTeX table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

Text removed due to containing thesis details.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please post a full minimal example that shows this problem, you are not proving a full preamble (document class is missing), and we of course does not have access to the files you are including

Comment: Have you tried running LaTeX another time? TeX needs multiple runs to get the references right.

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex` twice?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, running it twice worked! Can't believe I didn't try that before lol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, although it is a perfectly good question, it was solved in the comments by running LaTeX twice

Comment: @dipl0 Absolutely not :) It's a good question which now has a good answer :) But since the question has been solved in the comments, it's as well to close it to keep the site tidy :) It's just about book-keeping, nothing else :) Keep asking!